# How to read a variable in set_param SIMULINK function?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am having a problem reading a value from a file and put it inside Set_param function which will change SIMULINK model parametrs. This is my code where here i get the value of A from a txt file but i want to put A in Set_param. 
when the simulink open it shows A not the value of A in the model.

```
open_system('Transient.slx')  %this will open the simulink model
% get a value from txt file and put it in variable A
A= dlmread('C:\xampp\htdocs\RCE\MATLAB\FYP_expirement\SpeedControl\exp_value.txt');
% here when i put the variable A the function does not accept it
set_param('Transient/Gain','Gain','A')
```

i try A without single quotation also it gives error.

```
set_param('Transient/Gain','Gain', A)
```

how i can insert a variable in this function ? or is there any other solution ?

Comment: What do you mean by "does not accept it"?  What is the exact error message?  Your first syntax looks correct.

Comment: it does not give an error, but in the module the value of Gain will be a character A which is wrong. I want the numeric value of A that will be get from the file. It only gives error when i do not put the single quotation.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you very much i find a way to make it works. it seems that set_param only accept characters. So after getting the value i should convert it to string like this:

```
A= dlmread('C:\xampp\htdocs\RCE\MATLAB\FYP_expirement\SpeedControl\exp_value.txt');
s = num2str(A)
set_param('Transient/Gain','Gain', s)
```

then when i insert s in the function i dont have to use  quotation.

Comment: Standard practice would be to have the string `A` in the block, as per the code in your question.  This is called **parameterizing** the model.  During model initialization Simulink will look in the MATLAB Workspace for the value of the variable `A` and use it.